# How to efficiently find prime factors for an integer interval

Tags: algorithm, primes

I have an integer interval [a, b] and consider each individual integer as an 1-element set initially. I then want to merge all sets that share a common prime factor.

A solution outline for this task states that I only need to consider prime factors less than the interval size because at most one of the integers can have that prime as a factor.

I just wonder if it's not enough to only consider prime factors being `<= interval.size() / 2`? Doesn't the above statement hold automatically hold true for all primes `> interval.size() / 2`?

Comment: What about the interval [9, 10, 12] where the interval size is 4. According to your suggestion you would only consider prime factors 1 and 2 which misses the 3.

Comment: @SaiBot you are missing the 11 there but still same result

Comment: I haven't tested it, but I suspect that primes <= 1 + (interval.size / 2) will work.  The edge case is where the first and last members of the interval share a factor, as with @SaiBot's example.  The extra "1 +" solves that case.  You do need to test this though.